# Is there a way to change prices

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, pricing

Is it possible to reduce and increase prices on all products at one time by a specified amount or percentage without having to manually do every product. That must be visible to the customer and not just run as a promotion as this doesn't appear to display the cheaper price on the product tile.

Comment: Is this in the context of Craft Commerce?

Comment: hi Brad.Just seen this message. Yes it is in the context of craft commerce.

Answer (score 1):

Yes simply add a sale with no product conditions which will apply to all products.